# Full Text Search on Google App engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

How can I implement full text search on app engine?

I have read http://www.billkatz.com/2009/6/Simple-Full-Text-Search-for-App-Engine
but this does not see to work anymore.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? If you've read the article you should have some idea how it's implemented, and should be able to start duplicating that behavior if the original doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

[Google App Engine - Full Text Search](http://gae-text-search.appspot.com/)

Answer (score 1):

App Engine now includes a full-text search API (Experimental): https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/

Answer (score 1):

Of course you aren't limited to Python :)

Docs for Full Text Search in Java are here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/